# extjs 4: how to add button to any custom form

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am currently trying to add a custom button that will be able to call when ever the user wants to add a new button using EXTJS 4.

Here is the TimeButton.js file that i want to use to create the button

```
Ext.namespace("Ext.controls");

Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
text: 'Time',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
handler: function() {
    alert('The current time is '+Date())
}
});

Ext.reg('timebutton', Ext.controls.TimeButton);
```

but when ever i try add it to any form i get the following error

```
types[config.xtype || defaultType] is not a constructor
```

Or would it be better to do something like this

```
Ext.controls.TimeButton = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,  {

initComponent: function(){


    Ext.apply(this, {                     
            frame: true
            ,height: 330    
            ,layout: 'border'
            ,layout: 'column'
            ,split: true
            ,cls: 'DocumentWindow'
            ,items: []

    }); 

    this.documentGrid = new Ext.controls.DocumentGrid({height: 220,
                agentId : this.agentId,
                columnWidth: 0.5})

    Ext.controls.DocumentPanel.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);


}
```

From what i understand this happens when trying to instantiate (create) a component that does not exist but i do not see where the error might be! is there an error in the code that I have posted?

Answer (score 0):

Define your button as a class, register it for using with `xtype` by providing `alias` property and instantiate it in the parent `items` container. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/o_nix/9BpTn/) is an example.

Comment: It have to. Does the example work for you? Have you removed your old code and replaced with the new one?